# Hibernate Search - applying facet on a query brings back no results

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm trying to narrow down my original query with one of the returned facets, but this doesn't seem to work, i.e. it brings back no results. The first time I call `list()` method, I get 8 products (out of 15 total, these are limited by `setMaxResults()` method) and the list of two facets: one with the count 14 and the other one with count 1. When I apply the first facet to the current query and re-execute the query with the `list()` method, I am expecting to see a total of 14 products, but an empty list is being returned instead. I can't see anything I'm doing that's different from the documentation.

Bulding query:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = org.hibernate.search.Search.getFullTextSession(session);

        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder()
                .forEntity(Product.class).get();

        Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.all().createQuery();

        FacetingRequest categoryFacetingRequest = queryBuilder.facet()
                .name("categoryFaceting")
                .onField("productCategoryId")
                .discrete()
                .orderedBy(FacetSortOrder.COUNT_DESC)
                .includeZeroCounts(false)
                .createFacetingRequest();

        FullTextQuery hibernateQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Product.class);

        hibernateQuery.setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset());
        hibernateQuery.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

        FacetManager facetManager = hibernateQuery.getFacetManager();
        facetManager.enableFaceting(categoryFacetingRequest);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Product> products = hibernateQuery.list();

        List<Facet> categoryFacets = facetManager.getFacets("categoryFaceting");

        FacetSelection facetSelection = facetManager.getFacetGroup("categoryFaceting");
        facetSelection.selectFacets(categoryFacets.get(0));
        products = hibernateQuery.list();
```

productCategoryId field on Product entity:

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
@NumericField
@Facet(encoding = FacetEncodingType.STRING)
private Long productCategoryId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this is a bug. Thanks for asking though: now that we are aware of it, we can work on fixing it. The ticket for this bug is [HSEARCH-2668](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2668).

There is a workaround though: you can make your field non-numeric. Just remove the `@NumericField` annotation and use `org.hibernate.search.bridge.builtin.LongBridge` to index it:

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = org.hibernate.search.bridge.builtin.LongBridge.class))
@Facet(encoding = FacetEncodingType.STRING)
private Long productCategoryId;
```

If you need this field for other purposes, you can just create a second field, and apply faceting on that second field:

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
@NumericField
@Field(name = "productCategoryId_facet", analyze = Analyze.NO, bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = org.hibernate.search.bridge.builtin.LongBridge.class))
@Facet(forField = "productCategoryId_facet", encoding = FacetEncodingType.STRING)
private Long productCategoryId;
// Then use productCategoryId_facet instead of productCategoryId in your facet-enabled queries
```